# Jasper report JasperFillManager.fillReport very slow

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jasperreport api-s to generate reports for my web application and i am converting the same in HTML , PDF , EXCEL and CSV formats . 
I am creating it in the following way .

```
JasperReport jasperReport = null;
JRDesignQuery jq = new JRDesignQuery();
jq.setText("select * from employeetab"); //SQL Query might return 10-1000 or more records 
jasperDesign.setQuery(jq);
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, dbconnection);
```

while executing `JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, dbconnection)` , but the server is taking too much time at times , and sometimes it does not even show up .

The issue is not very consistent . 
The application is deployed in a Linux Server .
I have also tested in windows but i hardly face the above issue .

Any idea what might be the issue ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting to HTML, jasper can be very, very slow.  This is because the HTML it is outputting is super verbose - if your report has 1000 lines in it, it could be several megabytes in size.